# Why isn't the static block of Child class executed when Child.name is accessed?

Tags: java

I am learning the static block functionality in core java.

```
public class ClassResolution {
    static class Parent {
        public static String name = "Sparsh";
        static {
            System.out.println("this is Parent");
            name = "Parent";
        }
    }

    static class Child extends Parent {
        static {
            System.out.println("this is Child");
            name = "Child";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        System.out.println(Child.name);
    }
}
```

I thought the output would be:

```
this is Parent 
this is Child 
Child
```

but the actual output is:

```
this is Parent
Parent
```

and I have no idea why.

Comment: i saw that but still have a question why "Child" didn't get print

Comment: see https://ideone.com/tnBVKJ when you use `Child.name` you don't initialize the `Child` class

Comment: @YassinHajaj It is not a duplicate - the situation is different.

Comment: @glglgl yeah the output was "Parent"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since `name` is a static field declared in `Parent` class, accessing it in the `main` method (even though it is accessed using the `Child` class name as a prefix) causes `Parent` class to be initialized. `Child` class is not initialized.

Therefore `"this is Parent"` is displayed (since the static initializer block of `Parent` is executed), `"this is Child"` is **not** displayed (since the static initializer block of `Child` is **not** executed) and the printed value of `name` is `"Parent"`.

Here's the relevant JLS reference :

> 12.4. Initialization of Classes and Interfaces
>
> Initialization of a class consists of executing its static
>   initializers and the initializers for static fields (class variables)
>   declared in the class.
>
> Initialization of an interface consists of executing the initializers
>   for fields (constants) declared in the interface.
>
> 12.4.1. When Initialization Occurs
>
> **A class or interface type T will be initialized immediately before the
>   first occurrence of any one of the following:**
>
> - T is a class and an instance of T is created.
> - A static method declared by T is invoked.
> - A static field declared by T is assigned.
> - **A static field declared by T is used and the field is not a constant variable (§4.12.4)**.
> - T is a top level class (§7.6) and an assert statement (§14.10) lexically nested within T (§8.1.3) is executed.